# Jquery conditional fade by window width

Tags: jquery

I would like to make the submenu fadeIn, but only above 850px window width. My code only works if I refresh the page, but I'd like to make it when I resize the window ( or change phone orienation ) as well. What's wrong?

```
function WinSize() {
    var winwidth = $(window).width();
    if (winwidth > 850) {
        $('#main-menu > ul > li').on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                $(this).find("ul").fadeIn(300);
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $(this).find("ul").fadeOut(300);
            }
        });
    }
}

$(window).on("load resize", WinSize);
```

Comment: Write your HTML code or create demo

Comment: you can use $(window).resize(WinSize)

Comment: @Ansar It will bind lots of events to same element. Will hit on performance AND debuging.

Comment: There's no need for any JS here - use a CSS media query. Aside from being designed for this exact purpose, it will perform better as it is hardware accelerated, whereas JS is not.

Comment: Yes you can use css media query like @RoryMcCrossan said, based on media query you can show ul li and put normal js code without width

Comment: Yes. Thank you! I made the fadeIn effect via css opacity and media query

Answer (score 1):

Try moving condition inside of your `.on`. Currently you are binding event when on load windows size is > 850 and not effecting actual `.on` events

```
function WinSize() {
    $('#main-menu > ul > li').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            var winwidth = $(window).width();

            if (winwidth > 850) {
                $(this).find("ul").fadeIn(300);
            }
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            var winwidth = $(window).width();

            if (winwidth > 850) {
                $(this).find("ul").fadeOut(300);
            }
        }
    });
}

$(window).on("load resize", WinSize);
```